# Matching values to element names in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Is it possible to validate attribute values against element names in an XmlSchema.
For e.g. For the XML fragment below, I want to ensure that the value in the **'thisShouldBeAnElementName'** attribute should be an element name. So, valid values would be 'a','b' or 'c'.

```
<root>
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c thisShouldBeAnElementName='a'/>
</root>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what will you be using this stuff for anyways?

Comment: Its for a workflow specification, the elements define the steps,   attributes define branching constructs, e.g. goto 'a'. Did a very basic xml in the question to keep it simple.

Comment: Well while XML Schema will just get you that far, you are free to first do XML Schema validation and then write your own validator which runs afterwards.

Comment: I am doing just that, wondered if there was a better more generic way. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSD 1.1 you can write an assertion:

```
<xs:element name="root">
  ...
  <xs:assert test="every $a in .//@thisshouldbeanelementname 
                   satisfies node-name($a) = .//*/node-name()"/>
  ...
</xs:element>
```

XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Xerces and Saxon.